# Monotonicity of function proof: Prove that $e^{\arctan x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) < e^{2x}$ for all $x >0$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that

> $$e^{\arctan x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) < e^{2x}$$ for all $x >0$.

I proceeded as below: Let $$f(x) = e^{\arctan x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) - e^{2x},$$ then I differentiated $f(x)$ and tried to establish that $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x >0$: $$f'(x)=e^{\arctan x}\frac{(1+x)(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})+x^2}{1+x^2}- 2e^{2x}.$$

Now, how to establish that this expression is negative for all positive $x$? It seems to be a very complex espression.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that the function
$$f(x)=e^{\arctan x-2x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-1$$
is decreasing.

**Edit for @AlexFrancisco:**
I write it step by step:
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=e^{\arctan x-2x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-1\\
f'(x)
&=e^{\arctan x-2x}\left(\dfrac{-1-2x^2}{1+x^2}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) + \dfrac{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\\
&=e^{\arctan x-2x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\left(\dfrac{-1-2x^2}{1+x^2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}\right)\\
&=e^{\arctan x-2x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\left( -1-2x^2+ \sqrt{1+x^2}\right)
\end{align}
where $e^{\arctan x-2x}>0$, $x+\sqrt{1+x^2}>0$, $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}>0$
and
$-1-2x^2+ \sqrt{1+x^2}<0$
because $1+x^2<(1+2x^2)^2$ or $x^2(4x^2+3)>0$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco You wrote "I doubt if you yourself could prove this function is decreasing.", but the derivation of this function is too easy. See edit!

Comment: Anyway I wanted to give a hint, but I'm surprise someone with high reputation deleted this unvalued post, perhaps he/she didn't know derivation!

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know checking its derivation is negative is not much hard. Please forgive my indifference.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any monotonicity argument: what you just need is the inequalities $\sqrt{1+t}< 1+\frac{t}{2}$ and $\arctan t< t$ for $t>0$. Both inequalities can be proved using functions given by formulas on left-hand-side are concave over $(0,\infty)$ and considering their tangent at $t=0$.

Then the remaining proof is easy, as $x+\sqrt{1+x^2} < 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} < e^x$.

Comment: thanks for your answer , however , this question is part of a calculus course and hence necessarily to be solved using monotonicity and not by other algebric methods.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $\;\mathrm e^{\arctan x}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) < \mathrm e^{2x}$, you can prove the same inequality for the logs, i.e.
$$\arctan x + \ln\Bigl(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\Bigr)=\arctan x +\operatorname{argsinh} x < 2x.  $$

By the following corollary of the *Mean Value theorem*; it is enough to compare the derivatives of both sides and their value at $x=0$:

> Let $f, g$ be differentiable functions defined on an interval $I$, $x_0\in I$. If
>
> - $f(x_0)\le g(x_0)$, and
> - $f'(x) <g'(x)$ for all $x>x_0$,
>
> then $f(x) <g(x$ for all $x>x_0$.

Let's check the hypotheses of this corollary:

- $\arctan 0+\operatorname{argsinh}0 =2\cdot 0$,
- $\displaystyle\frac 1{1+x^2}+\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}<1+1=2$.

Comment: Thanks all got clarified